# Sql Error with Table pivot

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, pivot-table

I am trying to implement a pivoted table in sql but it is not working. What I currently have is the following:

```
WITH Pivoted
AS
(
select vg.ParentProductCategoryName, c.CompanyName, sd.LineTotal
FROM SalesLT.Product p join SalesLT.vGetAllCategories vg on p.ProductCategoryID = vg.ProductCategoryID
Join SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail sd on p.ProductID = sd.ProductID
JOIN SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader as soh ON sd.SalesOrderID = soh.SalesOrderID
JOIN SalesLT.Customer AS c ON soh.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
pivot(Sum([LineTotal]) for [ParentProductCategoryName] in (Accessories, Bikes, Clothing, Components)) AS sales
)
select * from Pivoted p;
;
```

I get the error:

> multi part "Column name" Identifier could not be bounded.

If I removed the column names in the select part and used * instead, I get:

> The column 'ProductCategoryID' was specified multiple times for...

What I want is to have a view of the total Revenue (as specified by the sum of the lineTotal in the SalesOrderDetail Table) per each ParentProductCategoryName (in vGetAllCategories) stated (pivoted as columns) with respect to each CompanyName (in Customer). How to better achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: change `vg.ParentProductCategoryName` to `vg.ParentProductCategoryName as ParentProductCategoryName` so that your pivot recognizes the column you are specifying where you have `for [ParentProductCategoryName]`, or alias it appropriately.

Comment: Not the problem, no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you'd need a CTE for this.. but put your JOINS in a derived table and pivot that derived table instead.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (SELECT vg.ParentProductCategoryName,
                c.CompanyName,
                sd.LineTotal
         FROM   SalesLT.Product p
                JOIN SalesLT.vGetAllCategories vg ON p.ProductCategoryID = vg.ProductCategoryID
                JOIN SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail sd ON p.ProductID = sd.ProductID
                JOIN SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader AS soh ON sd.SalesOrderID = soh.SalesOrderID
                JOIN SalesLT.Customer AS c ON soh.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
        ) t 
PIVOT(  SUM([LineTotal]) 
        FOR [ParentProductCategoryName] IN (Accessories,Bikes,Clothing,Components) ) AS sales
```

or you could just use the SUM aggregate with CASE

```
SELECT  c.CompanyName,
        Accessories = SUM(CASE WHEN vg.ParentProductCategoryName = 'Accessories' THEN sd.LineTotal END),
        Bikes       = SUM(CASE WHEN vg.ParentProductCategoryName = 'Bikes' THEN sd.LineTotal END),
        Clothing    = SUM(CASE WHEN vg.ParentProductCategoryName = 'Clothing' THEN sd.LineTotal END),
        Components  = SUM(CASE WHEN vg.ParentProductCategoryName = 'Components' THEN sd.LineTotal END)
FROM    SalesLT.Product p
        JOIN SalesLT.vGetAllCategories vg ON p.ProductCategoryID = vg.ProductCategoryID
        JOIN SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail sd ON p.ProductID = sd.ProductID
        JOIN SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader AS soh ON sd.SalesOrderID = soh.SalesOrderID
        JOIN SalesLT.Customer AS c ON soh.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
GROUP BY c.CompanyName
```